# dojango test install results in 404

Tags: django

I made a fresh install of django 1.6.2 in it's own virtualenv. No syncdb, no other configs. The only other apps installed are pip, setuptools and dojango. I followed the instructions in this wiki page https://github.com/klipstein/dojango/wiki/Gettingstarted

when I try `127.0.o.1:8000/dojango/test/` or `localhost:8000/dojango/test` I get

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.o.1:8000/dojango/test/
>   Using the URLconf defined in dojango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ^dojango/ ^dojango/
>   The current URL, dojango/test/, didn't match any of these.

this is my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'dojo_tutor',
'dojango',)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^dojango/', include('dojango.urls')),
        # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

The wiki page says to use `(r'^dojango/', include('dojango.urls')),` but I tried both like that and `url(r'^dojango/', include('dojango.urls')),`. I still get 404

Comment: there are typos in your domains / urls: 127.0.o.1 should be 127.0.0.1 and localhost:800 should be localhost:8000

Comment: No they are not. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post it with 127.0.0.1 even if I wraped it in code tags so I switced one zero with o. I fixed the 8000 part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a silly mistake. Foolishly I had named my project dojango so naturally there was a naming conflict. Deleted the project and recreated it with another name. Now it works.